# NetBeans-Java: is it necessary to use object classes for a small-deal text based game?

Tags: java, netbeans

In my class, I need to create a program utilizing things we had learned over the semester. I was thinking about creating a small text based game similar to Zork or Adventure(1977), but would it be necessary to use objects and object classes for something like this?

Comment: Oh, it's more of a general question I guess than an actual coding question. I was just wondering if using object classes would actually be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... would it be necessary to use objects and object classes for something like this?

Define "necessary".

If the game is small enough you could *in theory* put it all into one `class` and implement everything using `static` methods, primitive types, arrays, standard types, etc.

However, that is not the right way to do things.  Java is designed for OO programming.  If you try to use it the wrong way, you will end up "fighting the type system" and your code readability and reliability will suffer.

To illustrate what I am talking about, these two are roughly equivalent in terms of what they represent:

```
  public class Player {
      private String name;
      private int id;
      // add constructor, getters, setters
  }

  Map<String, Object> player = new HashMap<>();
  player.put("name", "fred");
  player.put("id", 42);
```

but in the latter case, the code base will be full of things like this:

```
  int currentId = (Integer)(player.get("id"));
```

which is fragile in at least two respects.  If you mistyped the `"id"` string, you would get a `NullPointerException`.  If you got the type wrong. you would get a `ClassCastException`.  In both cases, the compiler can't help you; these are unchecked exceptions.

---

Summary: it is not absolutely / strictly necessary, but you would be (frankly) **nuts** if you didn't make appropriate use of custom classes and objects in even a tiny Java program.